# Cannot link program using cairo-rs: "linking with `cc` failed" and "library not found for -lgobject-2.0"

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@bit101/intro-to-cairo-graphics-in-rust-35470a6aed86) to use cairo-rs to draw some stuff to an image. When I run my code, I get a very lengthy error. The important bits seem to be:

```
linking with "cc" failed: exit code: 1
```

and

```
ld: library not found for -lgobject-2.0 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

I installed Cairo through MacPorts, so that shouldn't be a problem. I copied the Cargo.toml file from the tutorial, except with up-to-date packages:

```
[dependencies]
png = "0.12.0"
cairo-rs = {version = "0.4.1", features = ["png"]}
```

I also tried with the versions listed in the tutorial, but I get the same error.

[Rust issue 18610](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18610) seems to have a similar error, and suggests installing `libc-dev`. I don't know what that is or why it would fix anything.

I saw somewhere that it could be a naming conflict, so I changed the name of my project so as to not conflict, but it didn't help.

### Details

- I am on stable Rust, I even reinstalled it.
- MacOS High Sierra, version 10.13.3 (17D47)

#### Full error

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-m64" "-L" "/Users/davidsullivan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.138pesuvab4dy035.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.15kq92zzbmxot4k9.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.16u6js6g0l3k1ic6.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.18w6p8ltrgxnoslg.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.1kduva7sc7em934m.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.1vut2eft6nlujjxr.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.1y16o1qfye96o7m0.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.1zeawhkbeobww1zn.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.2f1hnlzab9mh7h5g.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.2jqywn86b2gsqohu.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.2qhkzqx5zqexj20y.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.3171x0bwu82dptu7.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.3bupun14v400xrjn.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.3cx7oljifvb206q7.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.3gri9e66l1z4vy9t.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.3rngp6bm2u2q5z0y.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.45nf4z58qqykpcpi.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.49a7n47po4ttqjl7.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.49lx1q7cxvpykyv0.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.4ezmh1vbs95c5ack.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.4pd8ez09p90ytr94.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.4xq48u46a1pwiqn7.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.4yh8x2b62dcih00t.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.5adk9fi3m3eo99v4.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.8xzrsc1ux72v29j.rcgu.o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.9elsx31vb4it187.rcgu.o" "-o" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/using_cairo-0c2716712c3e8ee6.crate.allocator.rcgu.o" "-Wl,-dead_strip" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/Users/davidsullivan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/libcairo-02af06cb5f843585.rlib" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/libglib-9b2eaf5a04b666f1.rlib" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/libgobject_sys-dffb3413958eb3eb.rlib" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/libglib_sys-d80b4885044879d2.rlib" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/liblazy_static-ecb17a6c9c859f76.rlib" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/libbitflags-bcdfdc861d8d5eb6.rlib" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/libc_vec-21d683c350f5dff1.rlib" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/libcairo_sys-778a9ff4a1493728.rlib" "/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/Rust/graphics/using_cairo/target/debug/deps/liblibc-83288e07e4750a07.rlib" "/Users/davidsullivan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libstd-844f948b7f44d010.rlib" "/Users/davidsullivan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libpanic_unwind-1d305abaf51b5849.rlib" "/Users/davidsullivan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/liballoc_jemalloc-480b35384c455cd2.rlib" "/Users/davidsullivan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libunwind-579e24175a3d2d71.rlib" "/Users/davidsullivan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/liballoc_system-2600026bf2ff8eb5.rlib" "/Users/davidsullivan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/liblibc-7bb0ccf08d309fa4.rlib" "/Users/davidsullivan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/liballoc-d90d94404b7883e9.rlib" "/Users/davidsullivan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libstd_unicode-6be41d1b0b4956a1.rlib" "/Users/davidsullivan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libcore-788f4f091335111f.rlib" "/Users/davidsullivan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libcompiler_builtins-e26406cc89e6bd21.rlib" "-l" "gobject-2.0" "-l" "glib-2.0" "-l" "gobject-2.0" "-l" "cairo" "-l" "System" "-l" "resolv" "-l" "pthread" "-l" "c" "-l" "m"
  = note: ld: library not found for -lgobject-2.0
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

#### Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "using_cairo"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["davidsullivan <touisbetterthanpi@gmail.com>"]

[dependencies]
png = "0.12.0"
cairo-rs = {version = "0.4.1", features = ["png"]}
```

#### main.rs

```
extern crate cairo;

use cairo::{Context, Format, ImageSurface};
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let surface = ImageSurface::create(Format::ARgb32, 600, 600).expect("could not create surface");
    let context = Context::new(&surface);

    context.set_source_rgb(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    context.paint();

    let mut file = File::create("output.png").expect("Could not create file");

    surface
        .write_to_png(&mut file)
        .expect("could not write to file");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install the proper development libraries of `glib` and `cairo`.

If your OS is Debian related, type `apt install libglib2.0-dev`.

If you are using macOS and Homebrew, type `brew install glib` then `brew install cairo`.

Comment: Got the same error while running `cargo install exa` on Ubuntu 18.04. Worked for me. Thx